# How does it feel to type with Google Glass?

Tags: input, text, wearables, google-glass

Does Google Glass come with any note-taking or text-based application? I'm quite curious about the possible ways of inputting text using the Glass, apart from speech-input, and how it actually feels.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is off-topic because the answer could be found by reading the documentation and speaking to users. It's not a question for us as UX professionals.

Comment: Glass is still more about augmenting your mobile device than actually replacing it. What you're looking at, with Glass, is the first step of an unbundling process in which the functionality of the phone is distributed into a dozen linked & specialized devices. Your connection will be a very small key fob whereas your screens like glass or a small tablet will be fairly dumb. Heavy processing loads will be passed off to networks (like AWS), or a local computer at the home/office, then the result will be streamed back.

Thus, a note taking app would be something linked into a larger ecosystem.

Answer (score 2):

The question is a little odd, since it presumes two things about the Glass UX that aren't really true:

1. It assumes there is a keyboard, or that users will frequently use a keyboard. This isn't true - most interaction with Glass is done using voice commands or, occasionally, by some very basic gestures on a touch pad. The entire UX surrounding Glass rests on this point - many computing tasks work better without a keyboard, freeing our hands for other tasks, and letting us stay more connected to the world around us.
2. Although Glass does have applications, the focus of them is dramatically changed. We no longer collect icons and apps on a home screen, but rather think about the tasks we want to perform ("take a note" or "send a message") and let the system focus on how to do that (ie - what app should get that information). To that extent - yes, there are several commands that are intended as text-based triggers and quite a few apps that use them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a demo of an keyboard app called Minuum (which is also available on Android phones) here: http://minuum.com/google-glass-keyboard/

You can see from the video that the input is from precise swipes on the side of Glass. However, without using it I have no direct experience of the UX.